# Copy raw data from the memory to a file (cuda)

Tags: c++, cuda

For debugging purposes I want to copy the raw data that I have in my cuda memory to a file and make it possible to read it again later on and send it back to the memory.

What's the best way to dump this to a file. 
The type of the variable that is in there can change.

Comment: You'll need to copy the data from GPU memory back to main memory, then write to file.

Answer (score 2):

There's really no direct way to go from cuda device memory to a file.

So you'll need to copy the data back to the host first.  For whatever data is on your device, create the same kind of data (pointer, and allocation) on the host.  Then do a `cudaMemcpy` [operation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741) specifying `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost`.

Then use whatever you think is the best method to dump host memory to a file.  There's nothing CUDA-specific about that.